# Upload progress bar – Brower compatibility problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, file-upload, cross-browser, progress-bar

Having some issues related to browser compatibility.  I’m using UltraMega Tech’s upload progress bar code as shown below.  The code produces a status bar which tracks the progress of a user submitted file. It works perfectly for IE9 and Firefox, but that is not the case with Chrome.  With Chrome the form disappears and the upload bar appears, but the bar doesn’t move to track the file upload. However, the file is still uploaded. Any ideas?

```
<style>
  #progress-bar, #upload-frame {display: none;}
</style>

<script>
        (function ($) {
            // We'll use this to cache the progress bar node
            var pbar;

            // This flag determines if the upload has started
            var started = false;

            $(function () {

                // Start progress tracking when the form is submitted
                $('#usp_form').submit(function() {

                    // Hide the form
                    $('#usp_form').hide();

                    // Cache the progress bar
                    pbar = $('#progress-bar');

                    // Show the progress bar, initialize the jQuery UI plugin
                    pbar.show().progressbar();

                    // We know the upload is complete when the frame loads
                    $('#upload-frame').load(function () {

                        // This is to prevent infinite loop in case the upload is too fast
                        started = true;

                    });

                    // Start updating progress after a 1 second delay
                    setTimeout(function () {

                        // We pass the upload identifier to our function
                        updateProgress($('#uid').val());

                    }, 1000);

                });

            });

            function updateProgress(id) {

                var time = new Date().getTime();

                // Make a GET request to the server, Pass our upload identifier as a parameter
                $.get('http://example.com/getprogress.php', { uid: id, t: time }, function (data) {

                    // Get the output as an integer
                    var progress = parseInt(data, 10);

                    if (progress < 100 || !started) {

                        // Determine if upload has started
                        started = progress < 100;

                        // If we aren't done or started, update again
                        updateProgress(id);

                    }
                    else if(progress == 100)
                    {
                        $('#Patience_message').show();
                    }

                    // Update the progress bar percentage, but only if we have started
                    started && pbar.progressbar('value', progress);

                });

            }

        }(jQuery));
```

getprogress.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['uid'])) {

// Fetch the upload progress data
$status = uploadprogress_get_info($_GET['uid']);

if ($status) {

// Calculate the current percentage
echo round($status['bytes_uploaded']/$status['bytes_total']*100);

}
else {

    // If there is no data, assume it's done
    echo 100;

}
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest only using this code in IE<9, then using the xhr.upload.progress event in modern browsers. (assuming you also use an ajax post in modern browsers with fileapi) If i had to guess, i'd say the issue you are having has something to do with the load event being triggered differently in chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kevin. I don't have much experience with uploading files or tracking them.  I'll have to look into xhr.upload.progress. Is this typically easy to implement? Secondly, what exactly do you mean if I can use an Ajax post with File API?

Comment: Sorry, i had to step away for a bit. This is an example of how you could do it with a modern browser, while allowing the fallback method for others: http://pastebin.com/sGP1kZTK

Comment: Unfortunately, the example didn't work off the bat, but I'm going to tinker with it and see if I can figure it out.  I've been having an issue with a conflict in the use of the $ so perhaps that could be source of the problem.